# How to link a Jbutton with code to open a file browser to select a file?

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

Trying to write a simple program and I want a button that when clicked opens up a file browser window so the user can select a file to upload to the program...

I currently have the following code that opens up a browser window...

How do I link this code to my existing button code so that when the button is clicked the file browser opens?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFileChooser Popup");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
    fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
    frame.add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent.getSource();
        String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
          File selectedFile = theFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
          System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
          System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
        } else if (command.equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
          System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
        }
      }
    };
    fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Can someone put this into an MVC for me? I need to do it for an exam and I have no idea how to do it...

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class Tab extends JFrame {

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Tab frame = new Tab();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

{
    this.setTitle("Cipher Toolkit");
}

// set the title
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Tab() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(500, 400, 700, 600);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmPrint = new JMenuItem("Print");
    mnFile.add(mntmPrint);

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);

    JMenu mnAbout = new JMenu("About");
    menuBar.add(mnAbout);

    JMenuItem mntmAboutTheAuthors = new JMenuItem("About the Authors");

    mnAbout.add(mntmAboutTheAuthors);

    JMenuItem mntmProgramVersion = new JMenuItem("Program Version");
    mnAbout.add(mntmProgramVersion);

    JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(mnHelp);

    JMenuItem mntmFaqs = new JMenuItem("FAQ's");
    mnHelp.add(mntmFaqs);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.setBounds(20, 10, 655, 520);
    contentPane.add(tabbedPane);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Ceasar Encrypt", null, panel, null);
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue, 2, true)));

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("LOAD INPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
    btnNewButton_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("SELECT OUTPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    panel.add(btnNewButton_2);
    btnNewButton_2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_2.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("ENCRYPT!");
    panel.add(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JLabel lblSelectShiftAmount = new JLabel("SELECT SHIFT AMOUNT");
    panel.add(lblSelectShiftAmount);

    textField = new JTextField();
    panel.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Ceasar Decrypt", null, panel_1, null);
    panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 2, true)));

    JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("LOAD INPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton_4);
    btnNewButton_4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_4.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_5 = new JButton("SELECT OUTPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton_5);
    btnNewButton_5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_5.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("DECRYPT!");
    panel_1.add(btnNewButton_3);
    btnNewButton_3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_3.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JLabel lblSelectShiftAmount_1 = new JLabel("SELECT SHIFT AMOUNT");
    panel_1.add(lblSelectShiftAmount_1);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    panel_1.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    panel_2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Substitution Encrypt", null, panel_2, null);
    panel_2.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 2, true)));

    JButton btnNewButton_6 = new JButton("LOAD INPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    panel_2.add(btnNewButton_6);
    btnNewButton_6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_6.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_8 = new JButton("SELECT OUTPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    panel_2.add(btnNewButton_8);
    btnNewButton_8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_8.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_7 = new JButton("ENCRYPT!");
    panel_2.add(btnNewButton_7);
    btnNewButton_7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_7.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JLabel lblSelectShiftAmount_2 = new JLabel("SELECT SHIFT AMOUNT");
    panel_2.add(lblSelectShiftAmount_2);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    panel_2.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
    panel_3.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Substitution Decrypt", null, panel_3, null);
    panel_3.setBorder(new TitledBorder(
            new LineBorder(Color.yellow, 2, true)));

    JButton btnNewButton_10 = new JButton("LOAD INPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_10.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    panel_3.add(btnNewButton_10);
    btnNewButton_10.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_10.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_11 = new JButton("SELECT OUTPUT FILE");
    btnNewButton_11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
            fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
            frame.getContentPane().add(fileChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    JFileChooser theFileChooser = (JFileChooser) actionEvent
                            .getSource();
                    String command = actionEvent.getActionCommand();
                    if (command.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {
                        File selectedFile = theFileChooser
                                .getSelectedFile();
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
                        System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
                    } else if (command
                            .equals(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION)) {
                        System.out.println(JFileChooser.CANCEL_SELECTION);
                    }
                }
            };
            fileChooser.addActionListener(actionListener);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
    panel_3.add(btnNewButton_11);
    btnNewButton_11.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_11.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JButton btnNewButton_9 = new JButton("DECRYPT!");
    panel_3.add(btnNewButton_9);
    btnNewButton_9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 100));
    btnNewButton_9.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

    JLabel lblSelectShiftAmount_3 = new JLabel("SELECT SHIFT AMOUNT");
    panel_3.add(lblSelectShiftAmount_3);

    textField_3 = new JTextField();
    panel_3.add(textField_3);
    textField_3.setColumns(10);
}
```

}

Nice one lid

Comment: You have already **selected** the file. What do you mean when you say "open file"?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit broad and vague, since you show borrowed code only and don't show where you have tried to synthesize things together yourself yet, and so I can only post a broad outline of what is recommended. If you need more specific help, please show us ***your*** code and then tell us what problems you may be having with your code.

1. Create your JButton
2. Add an ActionListener to your JButton
3. In that ActionListener's actionPerformed code, open up your JFileChooser.
4. If the user presses the "open" button on the JFileChooser (tested by checking the int returned from the file chooser's `showOpenDialg(...)` method) get the selected File from the JFileChooser.
5. Done.

The tutorials will give you the details, and you will then want to write the code.

Links:

- [Swing Links](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)
- [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [JFileChooser Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)
- [JButton Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)
- [Swing event handling tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)
- [ActionListener Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

---

**Edit**
The key to giving a JButton desired actions is to add an ActionListener to it. I often do this with an anonymous inner class that calls another method of the outer class. For example:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      myButtonAction();
   }
});

private void myButtonAction() {
   // here put in code that you want to happen when the button is pressed
}
```

But again, there is no substitute for your reading the tutorials and experimenting with your code, writing lots and lots of code, to see what works, what doesn't work, what you like.

Comment: This is the code for my button that I already have. The code for the file browser has been found online. When the button is clicked, I want the file browser to open. I just dont know how to link the file browser code to the button.

JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("LOAD INPUT FILE");
  panel.add(btnNewButton_1);
  btnNewButton_1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (600,100));
  btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));

Comment: @itchyhippo: please note that code looses formatting when posted in comments, and for this reason, most all code should be posted in your question. You can edit your question and place this code in there. But much more important is my key recommendation that you have a look at the tutorial links and that you first try to synthesize your own code to solve this problem. If that doesn't work, then please post **this code** as an edit to your question, and let's work on it. Learning to program means learning to use general information and apply it to your specific situation, so please have at it.

Comment: @itchyhippo: most important, I don't see anywhere in your code in your comment where you yet try to add an ActionListener to your button. Please try this first. You are insulting yourself by thinking yourself not capable of doing this, and I feel strongly that you do have the ability, so please prove me right.

Comment: @itchyhippo: for instance, see edit to answer. Keep coding, writing lots and lots of code. That's how you learn.